# glob in Node.js and return only the match (no leading path)

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, glob

I need to glob `./../path/to/files/**/*.txt` but instead of receiving matches like this:

`./../path/to/files/subdir/file.txt`

I need the root stripped off:

`subdir/file.txt`

Presently, I have:

```
oldwd = process.cwd()
process.chdir(__dirname + "/../path/to/files")
glob.glob("**/*.txt", function (err, matches) {
  process.chdir(oldwd)
});
```

But it's a little ugly and also seems to have a race condition: sometimes the glob occurs on oldwd. So that has to go.

I am considering simply mapping over `matches` and stripping the leading path with string operations. Since glob returns matches with the dotdirs resolved, I would have to do the same to my search-and-replace string, I suppose. That's getting just messy enough that I wonder if there is a better (built-in or library?) way to handle this.

So, what is a nice, neat and correct way to glob in Node.js and *just* get the "matched" portion? JavaScript and CoffeeScript are both ok with me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var path = require('path');
var root = '/path/to/files';
glob.glob("**/*.txt", function(err, matches) {
    if(err) throw err;
    matches = matches.map(function(match) {
        return path.relative(root, match);
    });
    // use matches
});
```

Comment: hmm unfortunately i'm on node 0.4.x and path.relative seems to be a later addition

Comment: @Rebe: You could snip `relative` out of [`path`'s source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/path.js). (or rename the whole module and pull in all in, which is probably a better idea)

Answer (score 24):

Pass in the the directory to the options and have all that mess taken care of by glob.

```
glob.glob("**/*.txt", {cwd: '../../wherever/'}, function(err, matches) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: I use this without the `cwd` when I want the file paths relative to the root directory of the node app. If used with [wavy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wavy), it makes it easy to require things from any module the same way (relative to the root of your app): e.g. `require('~/app/file.txt');`